# offline_access will be deprecated, does it influence session_key,secret of rest api?

Tags: session, facebook-rest-api

`offline_access` will be  deprecated, does it influence session_key, secret of REST API? If I store REST auth infomation, may it use?

Comment: It's not will be deprecated! It's deprecated for a long time and will be removed **tomorrow** (July 5, 2012)

Comment: @JuicyScripter how is July 5th tomorrow? =p

Comment: @Jack, oh, seems like I needed to sleep before writing this one %)

Answer (score 0):

This is not have effect on anything related to API querying nor authentication flow aside fact that you will not get permanent `access_token` and will need to get active `access_token` from user and extend it manually (if you need).

BTW, REST API is also not something you should actively use, since it'll be deprecated

> **We are in the process of deprecating the [REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/)**. If you are building a new Facebook app, please use the Graph API. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is the center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new features will be found.

Comment: because access_token is used in graph api, I want to known whether session_key and secret which rest authentication returned have same influence like graph access_token?